# How to code multiple columns of character variables into 0,1,2 based on their frequency

Tags: python, r, data-science, data-cleaning

I'm working with genetic data right now and are trying to code the genetic data (categorical data) into number 0,1,2. A simplified dataset looks like this.

Patient ID Gene1 Gene2 Gene3

1. ```
       C/G   A/G   G/A
   ```
2. ```
       C/C   A/A   G/G
   ```
3. ```
       C/C   A/A   A/A
   ```
4. ```
       G/G   G/G   G/G
   ```

There are always three levels in each column in the format of A/A,A/B and B/B. However, it is uncertain whether A or B is the major letter in each columnN. For example, in Gene1 column, there are more C than G, meaning C is the major letter. I want C/C (two major letters) to be coded as 0, G/G (two minor letters)coded as 2 and C/G or G/C(one major letter + one minor letter) coded as 1. Similarly, in Gene3 column, G is the most frequent letter, therefore, I want G/G to be coded as 0, and A/A to be coded as 2. Columns with two different letters like A/B are always coded as 1.

I want the output cleaned dataset to be like:

Patient ID Gene1 Gene2 Gene3

1. ```
       1     1     1
   ```
2. ```
       0     0     0
   ```
3. ```
       0     0     2
   ```
4. ```
       2     2     0
   ```

I have over 750 columns like this and therefore coding them manually column by column is not possible. Is there anyway I can have over 750 columns of genetic data like this to be coded at the same time. I've been stuck on this step for almost two days and any help is appreciated. Both python and r code are ok.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(across(everything(), ~ case_when(. == names(which.max(table(.))) ~ 0,
                                         substr(., 1, 1) == substr(., 3, 3) ~ 2,
                                         TRUE ~ 1)))

  Gene1 Gene2 Gene3
1     1     1     1
2     0     0     0
3     0     0     2
4     2     2     0
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. Sorry about the bad formatting of my thread, Im still pretty new to this forum :)